# How to manipulate numbers from the user in a method?

Tags: java, database, input

I want to perform a couple of methods, but only with the numbers the user will be giving, so the methods will ask for int x, and int y, and I want to put the user's data into those fields, for the example, I will be using the Scanner technology, I have an idea, that it could be something like:

```
public class TestClass1 {

    static Scanner scanit = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        //How to manipulate int numbers from the user, in order to use them in methods?
        
        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         TestClass1 pumpkin = new TestClass1();
         System.out.println("Enter your numbers");
         int coordenate1= scanit.nextInt();
         int coordenate2= scanit.nextInt();

     
     //Here works actually right
    System.out.println(coordenate1 + "and" + coordenate2);
    System.out.println("Common sum without method" + coordenate1 + coordenate2);
    System.out.println("using the method sum" /*Don't know how to implement it here*/ );
    System.out.println("here with multiplication as well");

    //this is another idea I think would work
    TestClass1.addition(coordenate1, coordenate2);
    TestClass1.multiplication(coordenate1, coordenate2);
    scanit.close();
 }
 
 public static void addition(int coordenate1, int coordenate2) {
     
     System.out.println(coordenate1+coordenate2);
     
 }
 
 

 public static void multiplication (int coordenate1, int coordenate2) {
     
     System.out.println(coordenate1*coordenate2);
    
 }
}
```

Comment: `int x = scanit.nextInt();` and `int y = scanit.nextInt();` - pretty much exactly like you already have. Please edit your question to clarify what you want.

Comment: `System.out.print("using the method sum "); TestClass1.addition(coordenate1, coordenate2);` - your method are `void`. To use them in a single print statement they would need to return a value (not just print something).

Comment: Yeas, but, I'm asking about, how to operate the methods, with that information int x= scanit.nextInt(); and int y, I mean, how could I be able to do so, keeping in mind that the methods themselves are asking me another parameters (public static void addition (int coordenate1, int coordenate2), hope I'm being clear

Comment: Not really. You have `coordenate1` and `coordenate2` **not** `x` or `y`. And it isn't clear what you're asking at all. You call the method with `TestClass1.addition(coordenate1, coordenate2);`  you even commented your code with `this is another idea I think would work`. That's how it works all right. You should try running your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen from the comments, you want to "execute":

```
public static void addition(int coordinate1, int coordinate2) {
  System.out.println(coordinate1 + coordinate2);
}
```

Right?

Well, if you want to print the value on that "using the sum method", you can change the return type from the addition method from `void` (no return at all) to `String`, using the `return` keyword, such as this:

```
public static String addition(int coordenate1, int coordenate2) {

    int result = coordenate1 + coordenate2;

    return String.valueOf(result);
}
```

Then later to call the method like:

```
System.out.println("using the sum method " + TestClass1.addition(coordenate1, coordenate2));
```

Or since your addition method already outputs the result, simply call it outside the first `println()` call.

Comment: That's right, it is what I wanted to see, using the class name plus a dot, and add the method, what you just did TestClass1.addition(coordenate1, coordenate1); it is brilliant. I put coordenates because the program is with the robot class, automouser, to move the arrow with coordenates the user will input, and it worked great, thank you for your help! also for the previous contributers.